# weak vs strong pointers behaving slightly differently in xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode

i have some code that was working happily in xcode 4.6. since i upgraded to xcode 5 one section was not working. it's not erroring. very oddly the exact same code with no modifications DOES work in the simulators, but does NOT work on devices. if i compile the same coe in xcode 4.6 it DOES work on devices as well as simulators.

it uses tony millions reachability class.

i have tracked down the issue but becasue itworks on simulators in xcode 5, i dont understand.

basically on a button click i check the reachability.

i have a weak pointer to a reachability object, which i setup on the button click - snippet below

```
@interface settingsViewController ()
@property (weak,nonatomic) Reachability *reachable;
@end
```

....

```
//called on click
/ Checks if we have an internet connection or not
- (void)testInternetConnection
{
    self.reachable= [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];
if (self.reachable)
{
    NSLog(@"reachability created");

}
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"NO OBJECT");
    }
//do more stuff.....
}
```

basically without changing ANYTHING in the simulators the debug console prints "reachability created" but on ANY device (iPhone/ipad, IOS6/IOS7) the debug console prints "NO OBJECT"

tony milions code to create the object using reachabilityWithHostname is below

```
#pragma mark - class constructor methods
+(Reachability*)reachabilityWithHostname:(NSString*)hostname
{
    SCNetworkReachabilityRef ref = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(NULL, [hostname UTF8String]);
    NSLog(@"init1");
    if (ref) 
    {
        NSLog(@"init2");
        id reachability = [[self alloc] initWithReachabilityRef:ref];

#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
        NSLog(@"init with arc");

        return reachability;
#else
        NSLog(@"init no arc");

        return [reachability autorelease];
#endif

    }
    NSLog(@"cannot init");

    return nil;
}
```

and on both the simulator and device the debug console prints "init with arc" as expected.

so basically it creates the object OK, but as soon as i test it on the simulator it is valid, but on the device it is null. that bit i dont understand.

BUT if i change the reachability object to be a strong pointer, the simulator continues to work AND the device works as well - in that when i test the reachability object, it is set and the debug console prints "reachability created"

i dont understand how the object can be null as soon as it's created ONLY on the device with a weak pointer... surely 
a) the simulator and device should behave the same
b) i have only just created the object the line before - how has it become null on the device if i'm using weak pointer?/

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted should never work.

The fact that it does work on simulators is an artifact of the imperfect nature of the simulator, not a reflection that it SHOULD work.

The compiler should be giving you a warning that creating an object and saving it to a weak pointer, it will be released immediately. That's how ARC works.

Use a local strong variable. As soon as the strong variable goes out of scope, it will be up to the caller to decide if it should retain a strong reference to the object.

Comment: this of course makes total sense. no strong pointer means it can be released.

Comment: stupid ie - sorry - having issues adding a comment.. it's really strange how the code compiled with a weak pointer in xcode 4.6 and debugged tot he same device works perfectly 100% of the time. and of course the simulators work happily with the weak pointer compiled with xcode 4.6 or 5. strange how it was behaving perfectly and consistently until xcode 5. I can't see how changing the compiler has changed anything. pointer changed to strong anyway!